Why is my Heltec LoRa V3 board stuck in initialization when sending messages?
I'm using a Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 V3 board to send messages via LoRa. However, my code hangs in the setup phase, specifically in the while (!LoRa.begin(868E6)) loop. The board never successfully initializes, and I'm not sure why.
I've set up my environment using PlatformIO with the following configuration:
PlatformIO Project Configuration File:
[env:heltec_wifi_lora_32_V3]
platform = espressif32
board = heltec_wifi_lora_32_V3
framework = arduino
lib_deps =
  sandeepmistry/LoRa @ ^0.8.0
monitor_speed = 115200


Here's the code I'm running:
#include <LoRa.h>    // Library for LoRa communication
#include <Arduino.h> // Base Arduino library for compatibility

// Define pins used by the LoRa transceiver module
#define ss 18   // SS (Slave Select) pin for SPI communication with the LoRa module
#define rst 14  // RST (Reset) pin to reset the LoRa module
#define dio0 26 // DIO0 (Digital I/O) pin for interrupt, signals when a packet is available

int counter = 0; // Tracks the number of packets sent

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);          // Start serial communication at 115200 baud
  Serial.println("LoRa Sender"); // Print an initial message indicating the sender is active

  // Set the pins for communication with the LoRa module
  LoRa.setPins(ss, rst, dio0);

  // Attempt to start the LoRa module on the 868 MHz frequency (standard for Europe)
  while (!LoRa.begin(868E6)) // LoRa.begin returns 'false' if initialization fails
  {
    Serial.println("."); // Prints a dot every 500 ms to show it’s attempting initialization
    delay(500);          // Waits half a second between attempts
  }

  // Set a "sync word" to filter packets and receive only those intended for us
  LoRa.setSyncWord(0xF3);

  // Print a success message once the LoRa module is initialized
  Serial.println("LoRa Initialization OK!");
}

void loop()
{
  // Print the packet number to the serial monitor
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);

  // Begin packet creation
  LoRa.beginPacket();

  // Write "hello" and the counter value in the packet
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(counter);

  // Complete the packet and send it via LoRa
  LoRa.endPacket();

  // Increment counter for the next packet
  counter++;

  // Wait 10 seconds before sending the next packet
  delay(10000); // Sends a new packet every 10 seconds
}


Problem:
When I run the code, it stays in the initialization loop, and I see only . printed continuously in the serial monitor, which suggests that the LoRa module is failing to initialize. I've checked the pin definitions, but I’m not certain they are correct.
Additional Information:
LoRa library: sandeepmistry/LoRa @ ^0.8.0
Platform: PlatformIO
Board: Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 V3 (ESP32-based)
Frequency: 868 MHz
Questions:
Are the pins defined correctly for the Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 V3?
What could cause the LoRa module to fail initialization in this context?
Are there any known compatibility issues with this setup on macOS M1/M2 hardware?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

At this stage it's either a hardware issue, or pins configuration... The code can't talk via SPI to the LoRa module. Is it the same on both devices? In which case pins configuration is the most probable culprit.
# EDIT
I just realized that the V3 has an s,1262. Sandeep's library doesn't work. Use radiolib.


Pin configuration check: I double-checked the pin definitions against the pinout diagram of the Heltec WiFi LoRa 32 V3 board. The pin definitions (SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS, RST, and DI0) appear to be correct.

I don't know what "documentation" you are referred to. According to ESP32 Arduino framework variants definition source code for Heltec_wifi_lor_32_v3 board and the schematic diagram v3.2, the SPI port and Lora connection is defined as:
// shown on both the pin definition and schematic
SS = 8
MOSI = 10
MISO = 11
SCK = 9
// shown on schematic
Lora_RST = 12
Lora_BUSY = 13
DIO1 = 14

I would suggest you read the documentation and the example codes that come from Heltec's examples instead of some third-party library.

I tried to change pins, but it doesn't work.

Which code doesn't work? Have you tried Heltec's examples instead of Sandeep's code (which is not for the Lora chip used in Heltec board).

I tried to use the Heltec's sender example, it doesn't work

Please update your Post to add a section for "update", explains which Heltec example (among more than dozen examples) you've tried and what "doesn't work" means? what error message? etc.

I tried this one Heltec_ESP32/examples/LoRaBasic/LoRaSender
/LoRaSender.ino https://github.com/HelTecAutomation/Heltec_ESP32/blob/master/examples/LoRaBasic/LoRaSender/LoRaSender.ino

but it doesn't work

I tried them all, changing libraries and using radiolib. But nothing, they don't work

"I tried to use the Heltec's sender example", you have another Heltec board configured as receiver?

I have the same problem, sender and receiver don't work. If I use Heltec's examples I see the text "Starting lora failed" on the LoRa led screen
